# Haskell: read fixed amount of data from named pipe

Tags: haskell, fft, pcm

I'm somewhat new to Haskell, and as a beginner project I'm trying to make a little music visualizer.

I typically use ncmpcpp+mpd as a music player, and due to that I have a fifo named pipe sending raw PCM data to /tmp/mpd.fifo.

What I want to do is read in a fixed amount of PCM samples from this file, perform an FFT on that data chunk, print the output and then repeat. I've looked at Data.Stream, Data.Bytestring in Haskell's library but cannot figure out how to simply get a fixed size amount of data from the named pipe.

I figure there must be a simple way to do this and I'm just missing/not understand something, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with `hGet` from `Data.ByteString`? You get to specify the number of bytes you want to read.

Comment: @Alec: Could you put this as an answer? It would also be good to add how to get a `Handle` from a named pipe (which I don't know myself).

Comment: Yeup that does it! I posted it as an answer after using your snippet to figure it out fully.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Alec, this is actually very simple.

Simply get a handle for the named pipe:

```
sourceHandle <- openFile "/path/to/pipe.fifo" ReadMode
```

and then use `Data.ByteString.hGet sourceHandle n` to read n bytes.

I hadn't seen examples using this method and simply thought that handles would work the same as readFile which can only do the entire file. So as I had assumed, I was missing something, thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it! Might want to mention that `hGet` blocks (or so I think) until it gets either the number of bytes you specified or EOF. IIRC handles are sort of equivalent to file descriptors on unix based systems.